# How to copy git repository as a branch of a different git repository?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have two projects whose source code are very similar.  I want to copy the first project repository into a branch (not a submodule, not a subtree) of the second project before I delete the first project.

The reason I have two projects is because two developer groups forked the original code `A` (not a git repo) and created repositories `B` and `C`.  I want to preserve both repositories' histories before I start making any changes reconciling/merging the two branches.

I am aware that this question was asked before on SO but I want an answer that results in what I described (a branch), not an answer resulting in a submodule or a subtree.

Answer (score 0):

In the target repository, add both Git repositories `B` and `C` as remotes and fetch from them. That way, all changes from there will go into your target repository. Then you can create branches off the remote branches so they exist locally in the repository.

You could even do a multimerge of those independent branches to make them connect and serve as the base of your new history.